# Add image to uinavigation item

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I am working on a ipad app where I am trying to style the navigation item(add an image) of a table view in a storyboard.
(following this youtube link 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_971346&feature=iv&src_vid=edDoXNQrBX8&v=9Pp-Vz-A7bo
)

I noticed that there is no image property for the navigation item, so i embedded it in a navigation controller.(set it as the initial view, set the image(navbar.png as you see in the pic, set it's name as test )  However, after i run the program in the simulator, my image does not show up and the title is "Peter" not "test" .

Ive also tried dragging a navigation bar unto the  "recipeList" but it does not let me. 
I added an image that i believe shows my entire storyboard so I Would appreciate it if I could get any insight into this.

Thank you

**Update** 
In case I was confusing, i am simply trying to get an image where i have the text "peter"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.png"]];
self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView;
```

Comment: Works however this is hiding the peter title, hmm. will setting the Z property fix this?